# Reconocimiento y pausa Consola

Tags: c#, consola, terminal

Buenas. Tengo una aplicación de consola hecha en C# para reconocimiento de voz con la clase `System.Speech.Recognition`  que reconoce el audio y lo escribe en un documento llamado tub.txt. Aquí el código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.IO;

namespace VoiceRecognitionForIvernAppConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpeechRecognitionEngine listen = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            listen.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            listen.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
            listen.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(reader);
            listen.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple); 
        void reader(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextWriter file;
            file = new StreamWriter("tub.txt");
            foreach (RecognizedWordUnit word in e.Result.Words)
            {
                file.WriteLine(word.Text + " ");
                Console.Write(word.Text + " ");
            }
            file.Close();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Mi problema radica en que cuando termino de hablar debo presionar una tecla obviamente el comando Console.ReadKey(); Porque de lo contrario se abre y cierra inmediatamente la aplicación. Precisamente quiero que la app no se cierre hasta que escuche algo , una palabra u oración , después si se puede cerrar , sin necesidad de tener que presionar una tecla. Si no que espere, escuche , escriba en el documento y se cierre después. Tampoco pondría algo con un if(word.Text.Equals("salir")) porque quiero simplemente decir quizás "Hola mundo" y luego se cierre. Leí la documentación pero no vi una utilidad así. O no se si la estaré pasando por alto. Si alguien tiene alguna idea la agradezco de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde puedo entender, leyendo un poco la doc, esta línea:

```
listen.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

provoca que el reconocimiento se realice de forma contínua y asíncrona (https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.recognizeasync(v=vs.110).aspx).

La aplicación no debería cerrarse, sino escuchar contínuamente. Podrías implementar un comando inicial, al estilo "ok google" o "hey siri", a partir del cuál comenzar a hablar a la aplicación.

El problema es que (según leo en la doc) una sesión de dictado continuo se cierra cuando el usuario deja de hablar. Deberías implementar un grammar para el hands off ("hey siri"), que se quedaría escuchando de forma permanente hasta hacer match con el texto configurado, y entonces iniciar el DictationGrammar(). Cuando el dictationGramar termine, volver a hacer switch al grammar de hands off.

La aplicación se cierra porque siendo asíncrona se separa de Main. Podrías implementar un `while (true){Console.ReadLine();}` al final de Main, lo que haría que escuchase contínuamente sin cerrarse la aplicación. Para cerrarla puedes utilizar algún evento tipo SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession, que te indicará si la sesión se ha cerrado.